# Converting Oval 928 rear hub to XDR

Tags: sram, freehub

I am building a bike with a SRAM Force eTap AXS drive train. I would like to change the freehub to XDR on an OVAL rear wheel.

Does anyone know if there are any XDR freehubs that would be compatible.  The Drive on Oval freehub is approximately 37.2 mm in diameter with 3 levers.

It is an 11 speed and I have tried to reach the Oval Concepts website with little success. Apparently, it was purchased by Advanced Sports Inc. All the links for Oval Concepts are broken, my only alternative was to leave a contact message, hopefully I will get something back. Given the state of the website I have my doubts.

Here are pictures of the hub, freehub

[image: Freehub]

[image: Oval Hub]

[image]

[image]

Not sure if the V3 on the hub or freehub means anything.

I did try a Sram 900 XDR Freehub and it is just a little too big.  39.4 mm drive vs 37.2 for the Oval drive.  No luck on an internet search for a compatible Oval XDR Freehub or what third party manufactures the Oval hub assemble.

---

More information.  It is an 11 speed and I have tried to reach the Oval Concepts website with little success.  Apparently, it was purchased by Advanced Sports Inc.  All the links for Oval Concepts are broken, my only alternative was to leave a contact message, hopefully I will get something back.  Given the state of the website I have my doubts.  Here are pictures of the hub, freehub and wheel

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Not sure if the V3 on the hub or freehub means anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XDR freehub bodies are the same "width class" as Shimano HG road 11 (and also Campy 8+). HG 11 freehub body splines are 36.85mm long while 8/9/10 is 35mm. If the hub you have now is 8/9/10 then in most cases no, an XDR freehub can't exist, the exception being hubs that were designed from the beginning to have a flange to flange spacing that allows for a different endcap set to allow switching to a longer freehub along with a redish (not common).

If it is 11 speed HG then basically the game you're playing is figure out if the hub you have is made by one of the big hub makers (Novatec, Formula etc). If it is (and presuming you've already emailed Oval themselves before asking here) you can potentially find a freehub body from a nominally different brand that fits. This is a huge goose chase and basically involves using heuristics to figure out who made the hub and what the freehub body you have is, such that you can then see which XDR freehub body substitutes for it and whether you also need new endcaps. The upshot is the big OEM hub makers do generally have XDR FHBs available at this point that can replace HG 11 ones.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the Haynes bike company stable of companies. https://hayesbicycle.com/products/trfreehubbody

They represent Reynolds wheelset. Reynolds made oval wheels. They also made Ritchey hubs and freehub bodies. Call them they can advise you on what current market hub body is compatible.